# Modificar información específica en colección de Firebase Database Realtime con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, firebase, google-api, real-time

¡Que tal colegas!

Tengo un problema y es que quiero modificar cierta información no toda, por ejemplo quiero modificar solamente la dirección y el nit (ver imagén) pero al hacerlo me borra los demás campos, ¿Cómo podría modificar lo sin que eliminé lo demás?

[image: Error]

Utilizo Javascript y de firebase `firebase.database().ref().update(updates)`

¡Muchas gracias!